# $\sum_{i\to\infty}1-a^{b^i}$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to show that $\sum_{i\to\infty}1-a^{b^i}$ converge ?

where $0<a<1$ and $0<b<1$

I guess it must be true from the physical knowledge of the problem.  How can we show it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We solve the problem by getting control over the size of $1-a^{b^i}$.

Consider $a^t$, where $t$ positive and close to $0$. This is $e^{t\ln a }$. Expand, using the power series. Since $\ln a$ is negative, call it $-c$. The power series expansion is 
$$1-ct +\frac{(ct)^2}{2!}-\frac{(ct)^3}{3!}+\cdots.$$
If $t$ is small enough, we have an alternating series, and therefore 
$$e^{t\ln a }\gt 1-ct.$$
It follows that if $t$ is small enough, then $0\lt 1-a^t\lt ct$.

Thus in our case, setting $t=b^i$, we conclude that if $i$ is large enough, then $0\lt 1-a^{b^i}\lt |\ln a|b^i$.

The series $\sum b^i$ converges, and therefore by comparison so does our series.

Answer (score 0):

Using the ratio test , set a(i) = 1 - a^(b^i), then using L'hospital rule: lim /a(i+1)/a(i)/ = /b/ = b < 1. So the series converges absolutely hence converges.